# Run different bash scripts, started by one bash startscript, in different terminal tabs

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, tabs

I like to run more than one bash script, each in own terminal tab.

Now what did i found:

- The follow run two scripts inside one terminal:

start.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
./task_1.sh &
./task_2.sh
sleep 5
exit
```

task_1.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    echo "task_1.sh"
    sleep 2
done
```

task_2.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    echo "task_1.sh"
    sleep 2
done
```

The follow are able to open a new tab on terminal:

```
xdotool key ctrl+shift+t
```

Now i have found the follow solution:

```
#!/bin/bash 
gnome-terminal \
--tab --title="task_1.sh" -e "./task_1.sh" \
--tab --title="task_2.sh" -e "./task_2.sh"
```

Thats working fine, a give a error message like, "replace the old "-e" by "--". If I replace the "-e" by "--", I getting after than only one tab. Dont get the 2`nd tab.

Comment: research the poorly named `screen` utility.  Search like `[bash] screen utility `. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Its looks for me it dosnt need the screen utility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run different bash scripts, started by one bash startscript, in different terminal tabs can be on some ways like:

```
gnome-terminal --tab --title="task_1.sh" -e "bash -c \"./task_1.sh
  exec bash\"" --tab --title="task_2.sh" -e "bash -c \"./task_2.sh
  exec bash\"" --tab --title="task_2.sh" -e "bash -c \"./task_2.sh
  exec bash\"" --tab --title="task_2.sh" -e "bash -c \"./task_2.sh
\""

gnome-terminal --tab --title="task_1.sh" -e "bash -c \"sleep 5; ./task_1.sh
  exec bash\"" --tab --title="task_2.sh" -e "bash -c \"sleep 5; ./task_2.sh
  exec bash\"" --tab --title="task_2.sh" -e "bash -c \"sleep 5; ./task_2.sh
  exec bash\"" --tab --title="task_2.sh" -e "bash -c \"sleep 5; ./task_2.sh
\""

gnome-terminal "" --tab --title="task_1.sh" -x "bash -c \"sleep 5; ./task_1.sh
     exec bash\"" --tab --title="task_2.sh" -x "bash -c \"sleep 5; ./task_2.sh
     exec bash\"" --tab --title="task_3.sh" -x "bash -c \"sleep 5; ./task_3.sh
     exec bash\"" --tab --title="task_4.sh" -x "bash -c \"sleep 5; ./task_4.sh
\""

gnome-terminal \
    --tab --title="task_1.sh" -e "./task_1.sh" \
    --tab --title="task_2.sh" -e "./task_2.sh" \
    --tab --title="task_3.sh" -e "./task_3.sh" \
    --tab --title="task_4.sh" -e "./task_4.sh"

gnome-terminal --tab --active -- bash -c "echo Hello Tab 1; exec bash"
gnome-terminal --tab --active -- bash -c "echo Hello Tab 2; exec bash"
gnome-terminal --tab --active -- bash -c "echo Hello Tab 3; exec bash"
gnome-terminal --tab --active -- bash -c "echo Hello Tab 4; exec bash"
gnome-terminal


gnome-terminal \
gnome-terminal --title="task_0.sh" -x ./test_0.sh
gnome-terminal --title="task_1.sh" -x ./test_1.sh
gnome-terminal --title="task_2.sh" -x ./test_2.sh
gnome-terminal --title="task_3.sh" -x ./test_3.sh


xdotool key "ctrl+shift+t"
xdotool key "ctrl+shift+t"
xdotool key "ctrl+shift+t"
xdotool key "ctrl+shift+t"
```

Comment: Some of above, need improvements like set title for every tab and start .sh file by every line, like test_0.sh to test_3.sh

Comment: The code above, which use "-e", need improments depend on follow bug: * https://bugs.launchpad.net/gnome-terminal/+bug/1726380
  * https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=784925

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your terminal,

`gnome-terminal -e command` or

`xterm -e command` or

`konsole -e command` Pretty much

`terminal -e command`
To make the terminal stay when the command exits:

In konsole there is a `--noclose` flag.

In xterm, there is a `-hold` flag.

In gnome-terminal, go to Edit, Profile Preferences, Title. Click the Command tab. Select Hold the terminal from the drop-down menu labelled When command exits. You should create a new profile for that and execute with

`gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=NAMEOFTHEPROFILE -e command`

Comment: For gnome terminal there does not seem to be a, -a parameter. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/gnome-terminal.1.html The list of parameters are given in the link above.

Comment: You are right. I mean the -e and not the -a argument. I fixed my mistake. THX