# Parallelizing Bash Scripts in Different Terminals

Tags: bash, terminal, parallel-processing

Let’s say I have two Bash scripts:

prog1.sh and prog2.sh

I know I can run these two scripts in parallel via:

prog1.sh & prog2.sh

However, let’s say these two scripts are operating in two different directories, so I’d like them to be running via two different terminals. Otherwise, I'll run into an issue with concurrency.

My question is, how can I run these (or more generally, an arbitrary collection of scripts) simultaneously?

I tried answers at:

[Run different bash scripts, started by one bash startscript, in different terminal tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64582739/run-different-bash-scripts-started-by-one-bash-startscript-in-different-termin)

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/582092/how-can-i-run-multiple-bash-scripts-simultaneously-in-a-terminal-window?newreg=2529ef31224a4e44ae7d374f8809eef9

and others.

Comment: " I’d like them to be running via two different terminals. Otherwise, I'll run into an issue with concurrency." what issue is that?

Comment: @erik258 Since these programs (not created by myself, but open-source) assume I'm in a particular directory, which don't align with one another. This prevents them from running in parallel easily.

Comment: each process has its own distinct current working directory

Comment: You can run these scripts in two different directories even though being launched from the same terminal. Try something like `cd <dir1> && ./script1.sh` for example.

Answer (score 0):

In your "**master**" script, you can have something like

```
workdir=( "pathToWorkDir1" "pathToWorkDir2" "pathToWorkDir3" ... )
progs=( "prog1.sh" "prog2.sh" "prog3.sh" ... )

for i in 1 2 3 ...
do
    ( cd "${workdir[${i}]}" ; progs[${i}] & )
done

wait
```

If you don't want to "**wait**" before exiting the master script, you will need to add **nohup** before the "pro${i}.sh", to ensure they survive independantly of that master script.

If the paths to work directories are **relative** to the start directory, you need the round brackets.  If the paths are **absolute**, you don't need the round brackets.